# Example of the change of measure proposed in Hansen (2012)

Tags: econometrics, finance, time-series, probability

In this question, I'm continuing to explore the tools used/presented in [Lars Hansen's Econometrica paper "Dynamic Valuation Decomposition within Stochastic Economies"](http://www.larspeterhansen.org/documents/2012_Risk_OpMe_E_Dynamic_valuation_decomposition.pdf) (2012).

I'm trying to compute an example of the change of measure associated with multiplicative decomposition proposed in Hansen (2012). This question continues from [the same example
discussed in this previous question.](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3000/multiplicative-factorization-of-stochastic-growth-time-series-solving-for-an-ei)

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}$
Suppose that
$$
X_{t+1} = A X_t + B W_{t+1}
$$
where A has stable eigenvalues and $\{W_{t+1} : t = 0,1,... \}$ is an iid sequence of multivariate standard normally distributed random vectors. Suppose that
$$
\log M_{t+1} - \log M_t = D \cdot X_t + F \cdot W_{t+1}.
$$
I want to show that there exists a solution to the equation
$$
\E \left [ \frac{M_{t+1}}{M_t} e(X_{t+1}) \mid X_t = x \right ] = \exp(\eta) e(x) \tag{1}
$$
for $\log e(x) = H \cdot x.$

From the previous question we see that
$H' = D'(A - I)^{-1}$ and $\eta = (F + H'B)'(F + H'B)$. How would I compute the change of probability measure discussed in section 6.3 of Hansen's paper? Under this change of measure, what is the conditional distribution of $X_{t+1}$ conditioned on $X_t = x$?

**Progress:** In order to compute the proposed change of measure, I first need to complete the factorization described in equation (20) of the paper. Then I need to identify the factor $\tilde M_t$. In order to do this, I need to clarify how equation (1)
here fits into the framework outlined in the paper.