# Why is the martingale factor a martingale in Hansen's 2012 Dynamic Valuation Decomposition?

Tags: econometrics, finance, time-series, martingales

In this question, I'm continuing to explore the tools used/presented in [Lars Hansen's Econometrica paper "Dynamic Valuation Decomposition within Stochastic Economies"](http://www.larspeterhansen.org/documents/2012_Risk_OpMe_E_Dynamic_valuation_decomposition.pdf) (2012).

This might be an easy question, but I can't quite see it. In the paper linked above, the factorization is presented in which one component is a martingale.
See p. 937. On this page it presents this formula and says

> Given a solution to (21), I construct a martingale via
>   $$
> \widetilde M_t = \exp(-\rho t) M_t \left [ \frac{e(X_t)}{e(X_0)} \right ]
> $$
>   which is itself a multiplicative functional.

Maybe it's easy, but I just don't see right away how to show that $\widetilde M_t$
is a martingale. How can I show this?

**NOTE:** This question is related to the following two questions:

- [Multiplicative factorization of stochastic growth time series--solving for an eigenfunction/eigenvector](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3000/multiplicative-factorization-of-stochastic-growth-time-series-solving-for-an-ei)
- [Example of the change of measure proposed in Hansen (2012)](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3009/example-of-the-change-of-measure-proposed-in-hansen-2012?lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that after the Perron-Frobenius problem is solved, you have $e$ such that
\begin{align}
E \left[\frac{M_{t+1}}{M_t} e(X_{t+1}) \middle | X_t = x \right]
 &= e(x) \exp(\eta) \\
E \left[\frac{M_{t+1}}{M_t} \frac{e(X_{t+1})}{e(X_t)} \exp(-\eta) \middle | X_t = x \right]
 &= 1 \\
E \left[\frac{\widetilde M_{t+1}}{\widetilde M_t} \middle | \mathcal F_t \right]
 &= 1 \\
E \left[\widetilde M_{t+1} \middle | \mathcal F_t \right]
 &= \widetilde M_t.
\end{align}

Thus we see that $\widetilde M_t$ is a martingale.